# How can I update Google Chrome InRelease?

Tags: updates, google-chrome

I enter:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

but Google-Chrome InRelease doesn't run!

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://opensource.xtdv.net/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://opensource.xtdv.net/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease               
Hit:3 http://opensource.xtdv.net/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease             
Hit:4 http://opensource.xtdv.net/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
0% [Connecting to dl.google.com (2404:6800:4005:803::200e)]
```

After 3 minutes, I see:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://opensource.xtdv.net/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Hit:2 http://opensource.xtdv.net/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease           
Hit:3 http://opensource.xtdv.net/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease             
Hit:4 http://opensource.xtdv.net/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease              
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release 
Reading package lists... Done
```

The `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/chrome-remote-desktop.list` file has this content:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Can't I just remove Hit 5 in the update list? I have tried it, but I only can remove both, 5 and 6!

Comment: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable

Comment: @DNilesh please explain what that link is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the Google Chrome update process working correctly, you will have to re-configure the Google software sources. To achieve this, open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chrome-remote-desktop.list
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list  
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade
```

In case you still have problems with the update process, check the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and remove any Google entry that may exist by executing `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`.